# is it possible to get the selenium headless chrome XHR response when using Python 3

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium google chrome headless to capture some content, what I am tried to do is parse the web page source code and get the data list which I want. I have to write some parse html and css code to get the content I want. code like this:

```
    @staticmethod
    def fetch_music_download_url_impl(music_name: str):
        chrome_driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.GOOGLE).install())
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_service,
                                  options=chrome_options,
                                  executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
        try:
            driver.maximize_window()
            driver.get('http://example.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=' + music_name)
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aplayer-list-download.iconfont.icon-xiazai").click()
            urls = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in
                    driver.execute_script('return document.querySelectorAll(".modal-body a[href*=\'http\']")')]
            for url in urls:
                if "listenSong.do" in url:
                    logger.info("fetched url:" + url)
                    FetchMusic.do_save_music_download_url(url)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("scrapy impl error", e)
        finally:
            driver.stop_client()
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
            chrome_driver_service.stop()
```

this code works, this is just a demo, and I have to write more code to match the data if I want to make it more perfect.  I was wonder is it possible to get google chrome headless XHR response content with the json content which I was want to get. So I could do more simpler step just parse the json response. This would be more simple and reliable, resource saving.

What should I do to get the google chrome headless XHR json response?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it using `selenium-wire` like this way:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
```

then using this code:

```
    @staticmethod
    def fetch_search_xhr_response(driver: any):
        for request in driver.requests:
            if request.response and r'api/search' in request.url:
                if request.response.status_code == http.client.OK:
                    search_response = request.response.body
                    json_response = json.loads(search_response)
                    if json_response["code"] == http.client.OK:
                        FetchMusic.handle_music_list(json_response["data"])
```